# How to restore missing collections in database

Tags: marklogic

I have a full backup over 50 million documents and set journal archiving to false.  A developer is accidentally deleted two collections in database.  How can I restore just two collections have been deleted.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't restore a backup selectively based on query criteria. You need to:

1. Run a restore from a time period before the deletion
2. Extract out the documents you want. I suggest using `MLCP` which can be extract by collection
3. Move the docs into your production database. You can again use `MLCP`.

In the future, you should consider backups with journal archiving which will ensure no data loss in a situation like this, because all history will be kept.